# Firestore Limit Array Field Entries

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore, so I might be missing something. What I am trying to achieve is, say

I have this: tableName/documentID/history-array

In this **history-array** a lot of logs are stored from an android app using Array Union. Now, I want this **history-array** to keep only the last **100** or **N** numbers of entry. So, the oldest data gets deleted if a new entry comes.

Is this possible in Firestore? If not, is there any way to do this using a daily task/job/function?

I am doing this because I want to keep the documents in size limit.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried.

Comment: You can use a cloud function to do this. Any time the document is written to you can check the size of the array and then drop the last of them down to N. And write to it again. Either that or use a cloud function to write to it in the first place and trim the array before writing.

Comment: @Fogmeister, can you give me some useful resources to do that? As, my database is LIVE with lots of data, It is important to do it right.

Comment: @AlexMamo, as I've mentioned, I am new in Firestore and couldn't figure out the right way to do this. As, my database is LIVE with lots of data, It is important to do it right.

Comment: @warrior3hsan do you have any cloud functions in your project at the moment?

Comment: @Fogmeister, No, I don't have any cloud functions at the moment. My project is already in the Blaze plan, so I believe I can add cloud functions. But, the problem is I am not familiar with node.js. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you have large, growing set of data, using an array type field is not really the best way to store it.  It would be better to use a subcollection with new document in that subcollection for each item in the set.  That will be much easier to query and modify.

But if you absolutely must use an array, Firestore does not provide any way to manage the contents of the array the way you're describing.  In order to change the contents of an array (without arrayUnion or arrayRemove), you will have to write some code that reads the document, iterates the list field values, changes them in memory to be what you want, then updates the array back to the document.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. The problem it is already a live project with tons of data. I am at a loss at the moment what to do. Also, there is always a concern of data loss or breaking some functionalities.

Comment: As I said, you're going to have to write some code to manage the contents of that array, either before new data is added in the client, or after the data is added using a Could Functions trigger or some other backend you control that runs periodically.

Comment: If your database is already live, you should consider creating a development environment as well, to test new changes like this one before putting them into production, as every change has the risk of causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a cloud function triggered by new data on fs. create a transaction that reads the previous history-array. verify the size of this array, if it is greater than 100, do a array.shift() and a array.push(newData). i think it is cheap in comparison reading all items of the collection.